# Is there a LARGEST_INTEGER macro or something similar? (C)

Tags: c, integer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How would you set a variable to the largest number possible in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273913/how-would-you-set-a-variable-to-the-largest-number-possible-in-c)
>   [maximum value of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int)

I need to use the maximum integer value in my my code, but I don't want to explicitly write 4294967295. Is it defined somewhere?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`INT_MAX` (for `int`) or `UINT_MAX` (for `unsigned int`) defined in `<limits.h>`

Answer (score 7):

Use [`limits.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h):

```
#include <limits.h>

int maximum = INT_MAX;
```

Answer (score 4):

There shall be a constant in `limits.h`, if I'm not mistaken it shall be INT_MAX

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <limits.h>

INT_MAX
```

Answer (score 2):

INT_MAX as defined in `<limits.h>`

Answer (score 2):

The include file `stdint.h` includes all different macros for the different integer types. In particular `UINTMAX_MAX` for `uintmax_t`.