# Is there any way by which you can find the max size of a data type?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you set a variable to the largest number possible in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273913/how-would-you-set-a-variable-to-the-largest-number-possible-in-c)

Can we find the maximum size of a data type in C langauge?

Comment: as in "maximum size across all platforms and implementations?"

Comment: I mean that how would one get the largest value that he can assign to a variable so overflow cant occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the maximum and minimum values you can store in a variable of a given data type, you can check with  these different constants:

LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h), for the rest.

Answer (score 3):

There is no maximum size. A data type has a size, and it remains constant in that implementation. You can get it by `sizeof(datatype)`.

If you ask for the maximal number representable by a data type, then for unsigned types you can just do `(unsigned type)-1`. This is useful if you just use an unsigned typedef (`size_t` etc) and don't know the exact underlying type name. For signed types, this won't work. There are macros for this though (including the unsigned variants)

```
INT_MAX /* maximal int value */
LONG_MAX /* maximal long value */
UINT_MAX /* maximal unsigned int value */
/* etc... */
```