# Storing value infinity to a variable

Tags: c, compiler-construction

The following code will set x as "infinity"

```
#include <limits.h>
int x = INT_MAX;
```

when I say `int x = 3;`, the compiler is allocating some memory resources for variable x. Whats happening on the compiler side when I say `int x = INT_MAX`;`.

Comment: `The following code will set x as "infinity"` who said that?

Comment: @self http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273913/how-would-you-set-a-variable-to-the-largest-number-possible-in-c

Comment: Exactly the same; `INT_MAX` is just a fairly large number, but certainly not infinity.

Comment: INT_MAX is not infinity, it is just a constant giving the largest number an "int" variable can hold. Basically the same thing happens with X=3 and X=INT_MAX

Comment: @Ank try printing INT_MAX and see what you get.

Comment: @self. haha.. ya I should have done that..

Comment: The use of INT_MAX as "pseudo-infinity" in the post that you link to is only for a very specific use. Suppose you have a function that may return either a small(ish) integer or a very large *unspecified* number. If you want to return only 1 value, then you need a value that says "yes I *am* a freakishly large number" -- and still has to fit inside the returned int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be no infinity value for `int`s, because `int`s have a fixed binary size. Suppose you have 9 digits to write any number you like. 9 digits is pretty big: it can go up to 999,999,999; but yet there's no way you can represent "infinity" with just that.

Integers on today's common platforms are made of 32 bits, so `INT_MAX` expands to the binary value `0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`, which is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (slightly above 2 billions). (the last bit is the sign bit and can't be used to make the number bigger).

To answer your actual question, no matter the value you put in an integer, the compiler *always* allocates the same size for it.

Floating-point numbers, on the other hand, are stranger beasts, and have a specific binary pattern to represent the infinity (or negative infinity) value. This is possible because of the way [IEEE-794](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) numbers are represented in memory: there's a sign bit, some exponent bits, and then a mantissa. Any floating-point number, be it a `float` or a `double`, can be represented as ±(bit pattern) x 2^(exponent). However, there are also special bit patterns for values that are "not numbers" (also called NaN for Not a Number), like the result of 0.0 / 0.0, and special bit patterns for infinity values, like the result of any number other than 0 divided by 0. (This is not mathematically exact, but that's the way it works.) If I remember correctly, infinity is represented by having the exponent part to its maximum value, but I could be mistaken.

Mind you, it doesn't mean you can store *any* number in a floating-point number. Per the number of bits, there are "only" 2^64 possible distinct values that can be represented in a `double`, which is a crazy large number, but still not infinite. As you get to bigger numbers (or just more precise numbers), you start to see "holes" in the values you can represent. For instance, there is a, well, infinite step between the largest finite number you can put in a double and the infinity constant.

The point of having a value for infinity is to provide a constant that will necessarily be larger (or smaller in the case of negative infinity) than any other value. In that sense, even though it sounds more impressive than `INT_MAX`, it does pretty much the same thing.

Just like `INT_MAX`, there's a constant for it, which, unsurprisingly, is `INFINITY`.

Comment: `Floating-point numbers, on the other hand, are stranger beasts, and have a specific binary pattern to represent the infinity (or negative infinity) value.` Can you please elaborate on this..

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit my answer with some more information on that.

Answer (score 8):

That will not set the value to infinity. With integers, there is no value that can represent infinity. Instead, it will set it to the largest value that an `int` can represent.

If `int` happens to be a 32-bit integer, then `INT_MAX == 2147483647`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not setting int to infinity, it is setting it to the max value of an integer. 2,147,483,647 for a thirty two bit OS. It is storing essentially 31 1's and a sign bit.