# Is `int` always signed?

Tags: c, int, language-lawyer, signed

I always thought that in C, `int` stands for `signed int` ; but I have heard that this behavior is platform specific and in some platforms, `int` is `unsigned` by default. Is it true? What says the standard, and has it evolved over time?

Comment: `char` is signed or unsigned and a different type than `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Maybe that's what you heard. But `int` is the same type as `signed int`.

Comment: "_but I have heard that this behavior is platform specific and in some platforms, `int` is `unsigned` by default_" - That's true for `char`. A `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned` by default

Comment: @CoolGuy Oh, this is interesting. Maybe I could update my question to enlarge it to `char`? I do not know if this is a "good practice" on SO.

Comment: All answers deal with `int` so changing your question to include `char` will make the answers look incomplete. I would not update the question. Just my opinion. I could be wrong.

Comment: Nah, There's already a question for that: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/3049655)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are quite right. As per `C11` (the latest [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard), chapter §6.7.2

> - `int`, `signed`, or `signed int`

is categorized as same *type* (type specifiers, to be exact). So, `int` is the same as `signed int`.

Also, re-iterating the same, from chapter §6.2.5/P4

> There are five *standard signed integer types*, designated as `signed char`, `short
>   int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`. (These and other types may be
>   designated in several additional ways, as described in 6.7.2.) [....]

So, for any conforming environment, `int` stands for `signed int` and vice versa.

Comment: Is it a new thing since 2011? What about K&R C and C89?

Comment: @Boiethios I'm not sure about `C89/90`, but it's all the same from `C99` and I see no reason for it to be otherwise for earlier days either.

Comment: In C89, under `§3.5.2 Type specifiers` it states `int , signed , signed int , or no type specifiers (...) the above comma-separated lists designates the same type, except that for bit-field declarations, signed int (or signed ) may differ from int (or no type specifiers).`

Comment: @Tardis Awesome...that's it. Thanks for the info, let me add it to my answer.

Comment: Sure, add it :-) It should answer @Boiethios 's additional question. It is worth noting, as the quoted language from §3.5.2 suggests, that also another synonymous of `int` according to C89 was "no type specifier", since in such a case `int` was implied, and that this implicit typing was removed from the the C standard starting from C99. There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189962/implicit-int-in-c-language#26190042) on SO about this.

Comment: Tardis, sure C99 foreward mentions about removing implicit ints, both as a type specifier and function declarations, too.

Answer (score 6):

`int`, `signed`, and `signed int` are all the same type.

The exact form of `int` *is* implementation specific; the range must be at least -32767 to +32767. There is no upper limit on the range. Note also that the *complement scheme* can differ too: 2's complement is common these days although 1's complement and signed magnitude are also allowed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) Wikipedia article, `int` is a signed integral data type which is at least 16 bits in size.

Comment: 100% correct, but it is always good to use primary authority like the standard. (just a nit, but a formally important one `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the comment, you are absolutely right.